# How can I automatically convert all Lucene TermQuery objects to PrefixQuery?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using `QueryParser` with a `StandardAnalyzer` to parse a queryString. With this setup, if I search for `"key short"`, it will not match the text `"keyboard shortcut"`.

I think it's because the queryString `"key short"` gets parsed as `BooleanQuery(TermQuery("key"), TermQuery("short"))`. If I wanted it to match `"keyboard shortcut"`, I'd have to search for `"key* short*"`. I'd like the QueryParser to do this for me automatically, ie produce: `BooleanQuery(PrefixQuery("key"), PrefixQuery("short"))` when given the queryString `"key short"`.

Is this the right approach? If so, how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a 'proper' solution to this, so I implemented a hack that appends wildcards to individual words in the raw query and then feeds that to the analyzer:

```
private static final Pattern QUERY_WORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<= |^)(?!AND|OR)(\\w+)(?= |$)");

...

String processedQuery = String.format("%s OR %s",
    QUERY_WORD_PATTERN.matcher(queryString).replaceAll("$1*"),
    queryString);

Query query = new QueryParser(CONTENTS_FIELD, analyzer).parse(processedQuery);
```